# Custom HorizontalFieldManager menu not showing

Tags: blackberry

I have created a class that extends HorizontalFieldManager so that I can display a label and an image on the same line with the label to the left and the image to the right. I want the user to be able to interact with the hfm as if it were a single field. I have everything working (focus, click action, etc) except the menu. When I press the menu button makeMenu and makeContextMenu are not called. How do I make it so that the correct menu shows when the menu button is clicked and focus is on the hfm? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you override makeContextMenu, in the Hfm? You might have to override them in the label and image.
Or, less elegantly, you could just check in the makeMenu() function of your screen if the hfm has focus (or its children) and then add your menu item there.